# Corners of the Unilateral Shift

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Let $H=\ell^2(\mathbb N)$ and $S\in B(H)$ the unilateral shift associated to the canonical basis.

> I want to prove that there is no orthonormal basis of $H$ in which $S$ takes the form 
>   $$
> \begin{bmatrix} 
> \begin{matrix}1&0\\0&1\end{matrix}&X \\ Y&Z
> \end{bmatrix}.
> $$
>   Alternatively, what I want is to show that there is no rank-two projection $P$ such that $PSP=P.$

I think I have a proof of this, but it uses some obscure facts from dilation theory, and I would be really happy with a quick, dirty argument.

---

*While writing the question I came up with an argument, so I will be posting it as an answer.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for any  projection $P$.

Suppose that $PSP=P$. Then
$$
PS^*PSP=P=PS^*SP.
$$
It follows that $$ 0=PS^*(I-P)SP=[(I-P)SP]^*(I-P)SP,$$
and so $(I-P)SP=0$, that is $$PSP=SP.$$ So $SP=P$; given any $x\in PH$, we have 
$$
Sx=SPx=Px=x,
$$a contradiction since $S$ has no eigenvalues.

Comment: I am interested to know how you got $PS^*SP=P$? It may be silly but I am unable to get!

Comment: @Happy: Since $S$ is the unilateral shift, $S^*S=I$.